# A Riemann-Liouville differintegral for all entire Dirichlet L-series. Could it be simplified further?

Tags: nt.number-theory, integration, hypergeometric-functions, fractional-calculus, dirichlet-series

It appears that the well-known relation between entire Dirichlet L-series and the Hurwitz zeta function $\zeta(s,a)$, with $k$ = modulus, $j$ = index of the Dirichlet character $\chi$:

$$(s-1)\,L\left(s,\chi_{k,j}\right) = \frac{s-1}{k^s}\sum_{n=1}^k \chi_{k,j}(n)\,\zeta\left(s, \frac{n}{k}\right) \quad n,k,j \in \mathbb{N}$$

could be used to derive a R-L 'differintegral'-expression for ${}_0D^{-\alpha}_s \bigl((s-1)\,L\left(s,\chi_{k,j}\right)\bigr)$ that is computationally tractable for modest parameters and yields all fractional integrals for $\Re(\alpha) > 0$ and all fractional derivatives for $\Re(\alpha) < 0$.

The approach was to firstly establish the differintegral: ${}_0D^{-\alpha}_s \bigl(\frac{s-1}{k^s}\,\zeta\left(s, \frac{n}{k}\right)\bigr)$ and then to simply sum these terms, weighted by the Dirichlet character. This culminated into the following expression:

\begin{align}
& {}_0D^{-\alpha}_s \bigl((s-1)\,L\left(s,\chi_{k,j}\right)\bigr) \\
=  {} &  \frac{s^{\alpha}}{\Gamma(\alpha+1)}\sum_{n=1}^k \chi_{k,j}(n)\, \left( m0(s,n,k,\alpha) + \alpha i \int_0^\infty \frac{m1(s,n,k,\alpha,x) -m1(s,n,k,\alpha,-x)}{\exp(2\pi x)-1}\,\mathrm{d}x \right)  \tag{1} 
\end{align}

valid for $\alpha, s \in \mathbb{C}, \alpha \ne 0, -1,-2, -3,\ldots, s \ne 0$ when $\Re(\alpha) < 0$. Where:

\begin{align}
m0(s,n,k, \alpha) 
= & \,\left(\frac{n}{k}-\frac12 \right) M\bigl(1, \alpha+1, -s\log(n)\bigr) + \frac{s}{2} \left(1-\frac{\alpha+s\log(n)}{\alpha+1} M\bigl(1, \alpha+2, -s\log(n)\bigr)\right) \tag{2} \\ \\
m1(s,n,k, \alpha, x)
= &\, \frac{s-1}{\alpha}M\bigl(1, \alpha+1, -s\log(n+kxi)\bigr) - \frac{s}{\alpha+1}M\bigl(1, \alpha+2, -s\log(n+kxi)\bigr) \tag{3}
\end{align}

and $M(p, q, z)$ the [KummerM-function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#:%7E:text=Kummer%27s%20(confluent%20hypergeometric)%20function%20M,function%20bearing%20the%20same%20name.).

Have verified the above numerically for a few principal/non-principal and primitive/non-primitive characters and it all seems to work well. Als, when $a \rightarrow 0$, we retrieve the values of the original L-series.

Q: There are quite a few KummerM functions involved (esp. for evaluating the integrand) and it therefore would be beneficial when further simplifications could be made. Have already tried to apply some of the known KummerM recurrence relations from the [DLMF-page](https://dlmf.nist.gov/13.3), however without any success. Are further simplifications possible?